# Find a 3x4 matrix A of rank 2 that contains Span{v1,v2} in its null space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the following vectors:

v1 = \begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\-5\\-4\end{bmatrix}

v2 = \begin{bmatrix}-4\\4\\-5\\5\end{bmatrix}

Find a 3x4 matrix A of rank 2 that contains Span{v1,v2} in its null space. Hint: if a,b,c,d are the entries in the first row of A, what do Av1=0 and Av2=0 tell you about a,b,c,d?

Comment: Please read [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) carefully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case future students run into a problem like this, I managed to solve it myself already:

From the given information, we know that $Nul(A) = Span(\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\-5\\-4\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-4\\4\\-5\\5\end{bmatrix})$.

Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&c&d\\e&f&g&h\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$ for rank 2. We can then solve Av1=0 and Av2=0 to get the equations:

4a+b-5c-4d=0 ;

-4a+4b-5c+5d=0.

Solving these equations yields:

c = (1/45)(4a+21b) ;

d = (1/9)(8a-3b).

To make A's first two columns linearly independent, we assign a=1 and b=1 on separate columns, yielding us matrix A:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&4/45&8/9\\0&1&7/15&-1/3\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Solving the matrix for the null space gives us $\begin{bmatrix}-4/45\\-7/15\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}s$ + $\begin{bmatrix}-8/9\\1/3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}t$.

You can confirm that Span{v1,v2} is in A's null space by finding values for s and t such that the null space would equate to $\begin{bmatrix}4\\1\\-5\\-4\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}-4\\4\\-5\\5\end{bmatrix}$ respectively (which in this case would be s=-5,t=-4 and s=-5,t=5).

Just as I wasn't deterred by the downvotes, never be afraid to try asking about questions that have already stumped you for hours!